# Implementation considerations: OData v. Apex

Tags: lightning-connect

We're going to implement lightning connect from saleforce to our own servers, and are deciding between:

1. Implement OData on our servers and set up lightning connect to use OData (2 or 4 -- not sure which is best yet).
2. Implement an Apex custom connector and have it talk to our servers via HTTP calls, using whatever protocol we design for ourselves.

Is there any reason to prefer one over the other? Note that we're not worried about the difficulty of doing the implementation. What we are trying to understand is whether one will limit us more than another, or if one allows us to do things inside salesforce that the other will not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OData is an open data exchange standard. As such, you should use it, if given a choice. The alternative, using pure Apex Code, is intended to interface with systems that do not understand OData and that you can't justify writing an adapter for on the far side for whatever reason (e.g. the server is already overloaded, you plan on replacing the software soon, not enough resources, etc). There's nothing *wrong* with it, and both methods will continue to be supported, but you'll have a lot less maintenance to do yourself if you go with OData.

Both will generally have the same capabilities in terms of what you can and cannot do, but OData will probably require less maintenance down the road. However, you can *do* stuff with your Apex Code, so if you wanted to do some "magic", like pulling from multiple discrete resources, or some more complicated logic than what OData allows, that would be a good reason to go with Apex Code. It's usually just unnecessary in most cases. Just be aware that doing so might also result in slower performance when using these objects.

Comment: Can you say more about the "slower performance?" From where does the performance difference come?

Comment: @jgoldbg Apex Code is marginally slower than using the internal services, mostly because of its very nature; it's a virtual machine running atop a virtual machine. On top of that, some very talented programmers took the time to write a very fast, highly optimized application layer so we don't have to (salesforce.com employees). Unless you have a cream-of-the-crop developer laying around, it's probable that your code won't be as efficient as the native OData layer. There's a few of them out there, but they're hard to find, and harder to keep (so I've heard).

Answer (score 0):

We have some customers who are using our OData-enabling solution (DataDirect Cloud) to present data, but also doing custom Apex integration entirely independent of us for any INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations to leverage existing business logic.

Their explanation for this dual strategy is that Salesforce Connect gets them very quick access to present the data from a programming perspective, but they can't go around their business logic.

Comment: how we can use Both Odata and custom apex integration simultaneously? Are they using 2 different objects for it or on same object?